# My code shutoff without any warning in cluster

Tags: linux, python-2.7, multiprocessing, cluster-computing

I use `pbs` to submit my code, and find it shutoff without any warning(in the output file and error file). I tried twice, and the code stopped at two different points.

And I don't it's a bug of my code since I have run it for many times in my laptop.

And the cluster manager told me he haven't cut any job.

So I am extremely confused. Is there anything I can do to get more information to find out the reason?

My pbs script is very easy:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N TEST
#PBS -q n_cpu
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=32
#PBS -l walltime=36000:00:00
cd /home/user/work/scan/
python run.py
```

The only reason I can think about my code is that,

```
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp

def fun(i):
  ...do something...
  subprocess.call(['cp', execution_file, execution_file+str(i)])
  ...do something...

def fun_parallel(self):
  p=mp.Pool()
  p.map(fun,range(64))
  p.close()
  p.join()
```

And the `execution_file` is about 100M size, will this cause some potential problem like: 1.exit before finish copy? 2.copy from a same file in different process at the same time?

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the correct error and output files? How do you know `the code stopped at two different points`?

Comment: @dekkard Hi, the output and error files are named by `jobname.ojobid` and `jobname.ejobid` so that it's easy to identify them. And in the code, I have many steps and each steps create some files. So that, ie, step1 corresponding to file1, step2 corresponding to file2...I check the files then I know the code stopped at different steps. But the files themselves don't give any useful information about the reason.